# multi column css issue

Tags: css

I have used multi column css to display my various ul lists into three columns. The following is the css that i have used

```
.columnsmulti {
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-rule: 0px double #666;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px double #666;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-rule: 0px double #666;
}
```

This is the html code.

```
<div>
  <div class="box_middle">
    <div class="box_top"></div>
    <h2><span class="arr_lft"><img src="images/arrow-new.png" alt="" /></span>5 Towns<span class="arr_rht"><img src="images/arrow-new.png" alt="" /></span></h2>
    <ul>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
      <li class="blue">
        <div class="sec_lft"><img src="#" height="28px" width="31px"></div>
        <div class="sec_mid">Seasons - Lawrence <span class="special_red">Specials Not Updated</span></div>
        <div class="sec_rht">
          <div class="top_badge"></div>
          0 </div>
      </li>
      </a> <a class="thumb" href="#">
      <li >
        <div class="sec_lft"><img src="brachs-logo.jpg" height="28px" width="31px"></div>
        <div class="sec_mid">Brach's In Lawrence <span class="special_red">Specials Not Updated</span></div>
        <div class="sec_rht"> 2 </div>
      </li>
      </a> <a class="thumb" href="#">
      <li >
        <div class="sec_lft"><img src="gourmetglattlogo.jpg" height="28px" width="31px"></div>
        <div class="sec_mid">Gourmet Glatt Emporium <span class="special_red">Specials Not Updated</span></div>
        <div class="sec_rht"> 1 </div>
      </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <div class="box_bot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above div is one set. There may be any number of sets. The sets should distribute properly into three columns.

The problem is the lists are not distributed into three columns properly. It looks different for each page refresh. Some lists are not displaying sometimes. How can i fix this?

Comment: Hey now it's work check to this http://tinkerbin.com/udxy8xHO

Comment: The problem is the content. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I don't think that the multi column css is really designed to do what you're trying to do with it. It's more to display simple paragraphs of text over multiple columns in a newspaper/magazine style.

Comment: I noticed that you are using the class 'columnsmulti', but you are never using that in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `table` not columns.

Tables are reliable and robust across all platforms and display types and degrade well.

As @billy-moat suggests, columns are for magazine/newspaper type layouts and in any case are not supported in all browsers.

The issue here is that you are trying to embed columns within a list entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code, as mentioned. For this purpose, you can still use columns but first, read a little more about them (e.g. [here](https://kolosek.com/css-columns/)).